# MaterialCalendarView decorator overrides selected day color issue

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I am having a problem with [MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) library.
Everything is fine until I select a day with a decorator because the decorator has the same color of the selection color.

Here is the normal click:

[image: click on normal day]

and the issue:

[image: issue with decorator click]

the decorator code:

```
public class EventDecoratorMonth implements DayViewDecorator {
    private CalendarDay date;
    private Context context;

    public EventDecoratorMonth(CalendarDay date, Context context) {
        this.date = date;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return day.equals(date);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        if (context != null)
            view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange)));
    }
}
```

and through xml the selection color: `app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/orange"`

the selected day text color is white, I used `mcv_dateTextAppearance` with a selector to change it to white when `android:state_checked="true"` and grey in every other case.
The problem is when a day with a decorator is selected that the `mcv_dateTextAppearance` is not applied.

Edit:
my selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/textGrey" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/textGrey" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/textGrey" />
</selector>
```

How to fix this?

EDIT 2:

I fixed using a decorator with ForegroundColorSpan color set to white, and on changeSelected date I remove old one and set new one

Answer (score 0):

Try using this selector for your text color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false" />

    <item android:color="@color/grey" />

</selector>
```

Comment: it's not working, my selector is equal to your. decorator still overrides the selector